# Show non-ascii characters in chrome console (without percent signs)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, non-ascii-characters

Is there a way to show non-ascii characters in Chrome console to be showed properly, i.e. without percent signs?

For example, I'm testing some local webpage. It have connection to three different javascript files. One of this files is located at `D:\[some non-ascii-characters]`.

And so, for example if this file is missing, I will see in Chrome console something like:

```
GET file:///D:/2%20---%20%D1[here will be more percent-encoded characters] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

So, I want to show the actual clean easy to read path, without percent-encoded %20 %D1 and so on.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an option to convert and there probably won't be one. Since this is the actual URL requested by the network it is what is put into the console. Doing any conversion on this can be misleading as to what is *actually* being requested.